# Columns of DF2 that don't exist in DF1 %>% create them %>% fill them with NAs

Tags: r, sparkr

I have `df1` with 4 columns (let's call them `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`), and `df2` with 2 columns (`a` and `b`). I'd like to add in `df2` the columns that it lacks from `df1` (so `c` and `d`) and fill them with `NA`s, in order to then merge the two. Normal R code would be the following (if I'm not mistaken) :

```
mdf <- plyr::rbind.fill(df1, df2)
```

But this doesn't work with `SparkR`'s `DataFrame`s : `Error: All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames`

How can I do that with functions that work on SparkR `DataFrame`s ?

(Obviously, I'd like something maintainable, not something which is basically adding each column by hand like `df2$c <-`)

Thanks

(While I'm at it, `names(df1) %in% names(df2)` gives me `[1] TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE` and `which(names(dt1) %in% names(dt2))` gives me `[1] 1 2`, what function should I use to have it return the names of the columns, i.e. `[1] a b` ?)

Comment: a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) example may help.

Comment: According to the error message, I bet `df1` or `df2` is not of the class `data.frame`. What do you get for `class(df1)` and `class(df2)`?

Comment: No, they are `DataFrame`s (from SparkR)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question. You can use dplyr::setdiff to find the columns that are not present on both data frames by name.

setting up the data frames (this also works with columns):

```
df1 <- c(LETTERS[1:4])
df2 <- c(LETTERS[3:4])

df1
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
df2
[1] "C" "D"
```

and to find the columns in that are not present in both data frames use

```
setdiff(df1, df2)
[1] "A" "B"
```

or to find the columns that are present in both data frames

```
intersect(df1, df2)
[1] "C" "D"
```